# How do I use the Dropdown from react-native-paper-dropdown in my project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I wanted to add a `TextInput` **dropdown** in my app using [`react-native-paper`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/).

But I found no such component in their documentation. After some research, I found a package that uses `react-native-paper` for the dropdown feature and it seems to be perfect for me. But when I try it out I get a small black text input with a down arrow on it. As shown in the image below
[image]

The package that I found is [`react-native-paper-dropdown`](https://github.com/fateh999/react-native-paper-dropdown)

I even tried it on [**Snack Expo**](https://snack.expo.io/) in the [`expo cli`](https://docs.expo.io/)  but that didn't work for any android device(QR scan). But surprisingly it's running on the *web* part of the **Snack Expo**.

Here is the link for the expo that I tried [(Click Me)](https://snack.expo.io/@satyam143/some-rn-drop-down)

Please help!!

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Provider from react native paper dropdown library

```
<Provider>            
        <DropDown            
            label='Project Status'
            mode='outlined'
            value={projectStatus}
            setValue={setProjectStatus}
            list={status}
            visible={showDropdown}
            showDropDown={() => setShowDropdown(true)}
            onDismiss={() => setShowDropdown(false)}
            dropDownStyle={{
                width:'100%',
            }}
        />                
    </Provider>
```